# bash: alias: : not found

Tags: bash, alias

I am using ubuntu 18.01,when I add below command to ~/.bashrc with vim:

```
# myself add
alias lsa='ls -lart'　　
alias lsl='ls -lrt'  　　
alias lm='ls -al|more'
```

for example:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# myself add
alias lsa='ls -lart'　　
alias lsl='ls -lrt'  　　
alias lm='ls -al|more'
```

save ~/.bashrc then run command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

get error:

```
bash: alias: 　　: not found
```

If I comment out myself add code ,It's ok.

for example:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# myself add
#alias lsa='ls -lart'　　
#alias lsl='ls -lrt'  　　
#alias lm='ls -al|more'
```

What should I do?

When I run command:

```
 file ~/.bashrc
```

it output:

```
/home/hello/.bashrc: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

My problem be solved.Thank you all.

Comment: Check using some hex dump command (e.g. `od -t x1z .bashrc`) if there is any _non printing_ character in your alias commands. That space between `:` and `:` is suspicious.

Comment: @andcoz seem there is no.I only add 4 lines code. As above I say.

Comment: @andcoz Yes ,you are right. error at I add 4 lines code.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.bashrc` file is mostly likely to have DOS line endings `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. May be you edited the file with an editor from a DOS machine?

You need to clean it up by running `dos2unix ~/.bashrc` which converts `\r\n` to just `\n`. You can confirm the presence of DOS endings in the file by running `file` command,

```
file ~/.bashrc
/home/user/.bashrc: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```